# How can I grep a list of names from case?

Tags: bash, shell

So as an example, I have a bunch of apps that are constantly writing to /var/log/app//nonsence.file there's nothing else those folders, just logs from this one set of apps. so I can easily do:

cat /var/log/app/*/nonsence.file
and I'll get a nice stream of the app logs.

Mixed into this stream are periodic references to people. I'd like to build a script to trigger when certain names appear in the stream.

I can do this easily enough:

cat /var/log/app/*/nonsence.file | grep 'greg|john|suzy|stacy'
and I can put THAT into a simple script thusly:

```
#!/bin/sh
NAME=`cat /var/log/app/*/nonsence.file | grep 'greg\|john\|suzy\|stacy'`
case "$NAME" in
  "greg" ) echo "I found greg!" >> ~/names.meh ;;
  "john" ) echo "I found john!" >> ~/names.meh ;;
  "suzy" ) echo "I found suzy!" >> ~/names.meh ;;
  "stacy" ) echo "I found stacy!" >> ~/names.meh ;;
  * ) echo "forever alone..." >> ~/names.meh ;;
esac
```

easy peasy!

the trouble is, the list of names change from time to time and I would really like a neater list.

After some thinking I believe what I REALLY want to do is add each name into the case section only. so what do I need to do in the NAME variable section to tell the command to grep the name referenced in the case section?

Comment: So... `grep -o`? And `grep -f`? Did you read the `grep` manual? And your `case` is missing `;;`.

Comment: yeah, the script there is just an example. I knew I missed the ;; the moment I posted, but cant be bothered to edit.

Comment: as for grep manual, yes, I read it, and that's why I know I can grep both locations, but as I asked, is that the best way to do this? I mean, I already have to update the script every time there's a new name, I suppose my real question is, how do I tell the NAME variable to grep whatever is the trigger for each case entry?

Comment: you know what... that's a better way anyway... I guess I need to edit my question.

Comment: How about `cat * | grep -wof name.list | sort -u` and store all names that you want to find in `name.list`?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do! Maybe could you post some `nonsence.file` as example!

Comment: To trig changes, see `inotifywait -r -m /var/log/app` and/or `tail -f` !!

Comment: @F. Hauri I kinda cant without going into too much detail and overloading the thread. basically I'm building a live boot environment that installs and configures certain programs based on what computer it loads on. the cat in question is actually checking the hardware addresses of the local PC and running scripts based on a list of known mac addresses.

Comment: @dibery ... yeah, that will work... but I was kinda hoping to eliminate the need to enter names in two places.

Comment: OK, then how about `cat * | grep -wof name.list | sed 's/.*/I found &!/`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cat file | grep` is a useless use of `cat`. Just `grep file`.

Command in a pipe are by default block buffered.

The `>> ~/names.meh` is just repetition. Just specify it once for the whole block.

The backticks ` are discouraged. It's preferred to use `$(..)` instead.

Each time `NAME=...` is assigned the file is read, while you seem to want to want:

> ... I'd like to build a script to trigger **when** certain names appear in the stream.

which suggest you want to react **when** the name appears in the script, not after some time.

You may try:

```
patterns=(greg john suzy stacy)
printf "%s\n" /var/log/app/*/nonsence.file |
# tail each file at the same time by spawning for each a background process
xargs -P0 -n1 tail -F -n+1 |
#  grep for the patterns
# pass the patterns from a file
# the <(...) is a process substitution, a bash extension
grep --line-buffered -f <(printf "%s\n" "${patterns[@]}") -o |
# for each grepped content execute different action
while IFS= read -r line; do
    case "$line" in)
    "greg") someaction; ;;
     # etc
     *) echo "Internal error - unhandled pattern"; ;;
    esac
done >> ~/names.me
```

Because specyfing patterns twice is *lame*,  you could do an associative function to map the patterns to function names, or just use unique function names and geenerate from them the pattern list:

```
pattern_greg() { echo "greg"; }
pattern_kamil() { echo "well, not greg"; }

patterns=($(declare -F | sed 's/declare -f //; /^pattern_/!d; s/pattern_//'))
... |
while IFS= read -r line; do
     if declare -f pattern_"$line" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        pattern_"$line"
     else
        echo "Internal error occured"
     fi
done
```

alternatively, but I like the functions better:

```
greg_function() { echo do something; }
kamil_callback() { echo do something else; }
declare -A patterns
patterns=([greg]=greg_function [kamil]=kamil_callback)
... | grep -f <(printf "%s\n" ${!patterns[@]}) ... | 
while IFS= read -r line; do
     # I think this is how to check if array element is set
     if [[ -n "${patterns[$line]}" ]]; then
            "${patterns[$line]}"
     else
         echo error
     fi
done
```

Comment: this works! while I would prefer not to enter the names more than just the once, this at least puts the names in one place and makes them a little neater to work with  (as they are at the top of the script and fairly plain to read)

Comment: I think you could define names the same as the patterns, and then just like `greg() { echo do something; }; .... while IFS= read -r line; do "$line"; done` or better do an associative array of names to functions.